# Network Service credentials not getting passed to Web Service

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis, credentials

I have two virtual directories under one site on the same machine. They run on IIS6 as the Network Service identity. One of the applications is a web service that should be locked down to only be accessed using certain credentials. The second application is a public site that should have access to the web service.

I have Integrated Windows authentication checked, and Enabled anonymous access unchecked on the web service. I have given the MACHINE_NAME$ user read and execute permissions to the web service directory (probably not required).

When I call the web service from the public site it looks like so:

```
var service = new WebService(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Url"]);
service.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
service.PreAuthenticate = true;

ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = ValidateCertificate;
var result = service.CallWebService(str);
```

What I would expect is for the Network Service account credentials to be passed to the web service and return a value from CallWebService. What I get is a 401 error.

I have checked the IIS logs and there are three posts being made the the web service when the method is called, but they don't include the credentials.

I have also checked the security Event Logs and there is a Failure Audit event when the method is called that looks similar to this:

```
Logon Failure:
    Reason:     An error occurred during logon
    User Name:  MACHINE_NAME$
    Domain:     DOMAIN_NAME
    Logon Type: 3
    Logon Process:  8e
    Authentication Package: NTLM
    ...
```